# How to pass a method as a parameter without using delegates and call it instantly?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, profiling, godot

**Briefly**: I want to pass any method to a static method and call it from there, but I'm not satisfied with the delegates, because they are not executed instantly, they have a delay. I need perfect sequencing of lines of code.

**In detail**: for example, if I try to perform manual memory profiling by passing some method under test as a delegate, it fails, showing 0 KB of allocated memory, because the delegates are not executed sequentially in the code, like a normal function call:

```
public static void RunMethod(Action function)
{
    long beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    function.Invoke();
    long afterMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    
    GD.Print("GetTotalMemory = " + (double)beforeMemory / 1024 + " - " + (double)afterMemory / 1024 + " = " + (double)(afterMemory - beforeMemory) / 1024 + " kb");
}
```

And I get 0 kb allocations, the memory before and after function.Invoke() remains 316 kb:

```
GetTotalMemory = 316.9453125 - 316.9453125 = 0 kb
```

I'm thinking about passing the name of the function and a reference to the class instance to the method, and then just using the reference to find the desired function and call it. How to do it more efficiently? Is there any way to pass the method directly without using a String? I don't like String, because this causes additional memory allocation. Or is there some better solution to what I want?

---

Delegate example I'm using:

```
using Godot;
using System;

namespace Test.Perfomance_GC_Allocation_Measure
{
    public partial class Test : Node
    {
        public override void _Process(double delta)
        {
            if(Input.IsActionJustPressed("ui_right"))
            {
                Tools.Profiling.RunMethod(DoTest0);
            }
        }


        public void DoTest0()
        {
            ushort[] collection = new ushort[1000000];
        }
    }
}
```

- 

```
using Godot;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Tools
{
    public class Profiling
    {
        static Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        public static void RunMethod(Action function)
        {
            long before_GetTotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            function.Invoke();
            long after_GetTotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            
            GD.Print("GetTotalMemory = " + (double)before_GetTotalMemory / 1024 + " - " + (double)after_GetTotalMemory / 1024 + " = " + (double)(after_GetTotalMemory - before_GetTotalMemory) / 1024 + " kb");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegates are the way to do this in .NET. If you need the delegate call to be faster, cache the constructed delegate in a field and pass that instead.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Why managed memory must change after invocation of the method? Especially since you pass true to GetTotalMemory.

Comment: _"it fails, showing 0 KB of allocated memory, because the delegates are not executed sequentially in the code"_ - I don't think you're reading this situation correctly. Unless the delegates are async, `function.Invoke();` will block until the function it represents completes.

Comment: @Sweeper, I added an example to the question.

Comment: @Evk, Because the method creates a large array: ushort[] collection = new ushort[1000000];. If I measure memory directly in the method, I get about 1953 kb of allocations, which corresponds to a theoretical amount of 10 million ushort, but not in the delegate.

Comment: Is there any practical usage of delegates that makes you think they are not executed instantly?

Comment: @Orion, @ProgrammingLlama, What could be wrong? If I directly measure the memory in the called method, the allocations are displayed correctly and I get 1953kb:

`
public void DoTest3()
{
long before_GetTotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
ushort[] collection = new ushort[1000000];
long after_GetTotalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

GD.Print("GetTotalMemory = " + (double)before_GetTotalMemory / 1024 + " - " + (double)after_GetTotalMemory / 1024 + " = " + (double)(after_GetTotalMemory - before_GetTotalMemory) / 1024 + " kb");
}
`

Comment: Just use debug mode then you will see it's sequence.

Comment: But if I call the same method through a delegate (an example added to the question), then I get 0 kb.

Comment: Why did you decide to pass `true` to `GetTotalMemory`? The `ushort` array is likely GC'ed at the second `GetTotalMemory` call, which is why you don't see any change in the memory usage. Though this doesn't prevent the `ushort` array from getting GC'ed at the second `GetTotalMemory`call, how about passing `false`?

Comment: [With a delegate](https://rextester.com/HQJB12766), and then [as a straight method call](https://rextester.com/BQZPE68823) (same result). Finally [without forcing garbage collection afterwards](https://rextester.com/PFUW65794).

Comment: OP, why are you even hung up on measuring memory usage? If you suspect delegates are not "executed instantly", this would significantly mess up normal program flow. Is there any actual problem that manifested itself and could be explained by delegates being executed out-of-order? Missing variable values, methods not returning, `if` branches not executing?

Comment: Oh! I did some tests and it looks like the ushort[] collection gets cleaned up before I measure the memory allocations a second time! If I declare an array outside the function, then I get the allocated memory. Also, if I put the argument false, then I get the allocated memory. I mistakenly thought that true allows you not to wait for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help in the comments, I figured it out:

**1**. Delegates are executed immediately.

**2**. I messed up the parameter value in *GC.GetTotalMemory(true)*. The "true" parameter waits for garbage collection to take place. That is why, when the call sequence returned to my *RunMethod*, the memory was already cleared and showed 0 kb. It is correct to use the "false" parameter.

**3**. For memory profiling it is better to use *GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes* instead of *GC.GetTotalMemory*.